# Получить сумму значений из нескольких столбцов для каждой строки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет.
Есть дата фрейм вида

> |one|two|three|four|
>
> ---
>
> First|sec|three|123|

делаю пятую колонку кодом

```
input['five'] = input['four'].sum()
```

Как изменить код так, что бы на каждой строке была сумма с учетом трех колонок one, two, three?

Comment: я что-то недопонял. Приведите пример данных и пример результата, который вы хотите увидеть

Comment: с такой формулировкой - непонятно что вы хотите сделать... [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 4)), columns='one two three four'.split())

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   one  two  three  four
0    3    1      2     5
1    2    5      2     1
2    5    1      3     9
3    5    6      7     2
4    9    6      0     2

In [10]: df['five'] = df[['one','two','three']].sum(axis=1)

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   one  two  three  four  five
0    3    1      2     5     6
1    2    5      2     1     9
2    5    1      3     9     9
3    5    6      7     2    18
4    9    6      0     2    15
```